# Existing constant variables are getting "TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined" error in unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a constant.js file in my Angular project. The existing constant.js variables are getting "TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined" error in Jasmine unit testing.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: app.constant('constantVariables', 

     {  TEST_CYCLE_STATUS: [{ statusId: '10', status: 'Invited' }, { statusId: '11', status: 'Joined' }, { statusId: '12', status: 'Draft' }
       , { statusId: '13', status: 'Submitted' }, { statusId: '14', status: 'Launched' }, { statusId: '15', status: 'UnRead' }
      , { statusId: '16', status: 'Read' }, { statusId: '17', status: 'Approve' }, { statusId: '1', status: 'Active' }
        , { statusId: '30', status: 'OnHold' }, { statusId: '34', status: 'Closed' }, { statusId: '35', status: 'Declared' }]
  });

Comment: post your code in the question and where do you use this constant. post that too

Comment: That also seems a pretty odd constant btw.

Comment: This is my controller  


vmSettings.testcycleJoinedStatus = constantVariables.TEST_CYCLE_STATUS[1].statusId;
        vmSettings.testcycleAapprovedStatus = constantVariables.TEST_CYCLE_STATUS[7].statusId;
        vmSettings.testcycleBlockedStatus = constantVariables.TEST_CYCLE_STATUS[17].statusId;

Comment: as i mentioned earlier in the comment edit your question

Comment: Project ctrl Test Driven Development should filter projects by status FAILED
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusId' of undefined
     at ProjectCtrl (app/tester/project/ProjectCtrl.js:9:3129)
     at e (scripts/angular.min.js:4:2732)